Getting no results in textmeshpro while trying to write text in it with c#
So im trying to make a story line unity game. everything is done but the story line. it was going swimmingly but this script turned out to be an issue. here it is:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TMPro;

public class storyLineController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public FPSController fpc;
    public vechileSwitch vs;
    private readonly string folderpath = @$"{Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)}\too-bad-to-be-true";
    byte[] bytes = null;
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    public List<string> messages = new List<string>();
    public TextMeshProUGUI messagesPlaceholder;
    public TextMeshProUGUI newMessageAlert;
    public int newMessageCount;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        new Task(Program).Start();
        sw.Start();
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@$"{folderpath}\ESSgr.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            messages.Add($"[{sw.Elapsed.Minutes}:{sw.Elapsed.Seconds}] program booted up \n");
            foreach ( var message in messages )
            {
                bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{message}\n");
                fs.Write(bytes);
            }
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes));
        }
    }
    void Program()
    {
        newMessageCount++;
        sendMessage("james: Hey bro, james here. get in the car i left you, its right next to you.");
        while (!vs.isInVechile) { };
        newMessageCount++;
        sendMessage("james: if you are in a car already, come by me. i have something to chat about");
    }
    public void sendMessage(string message)
    {
        newMessageAlert.text = $"+{newMessageCount} new message(s)";
        messages.Add(message);
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@$"{folderpath}\ESSgr.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            foreach (var message1 in messages)
            {
                bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"[{sw.Elapsed.Minutes}:{sw.Elapsed.Seconds}] {message1}\n");
                fs.Write(bytes);
            }
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes));
        }
        messagesPlaceholder.text = $"{messages[messages.Count]} \n {messages[messages.Count - 1]}";
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log($"messagePlaceholder text is: {messagesPlaceholder.text}");
    }
}



as you can see, im not using unity's default start and update methodes. that would cause too much lag because i would have had to write if code in update and that would cause a ton of lag. instead, i tried so call program methode asynchronously.
thing is, the first code line in the sendMessage methode, newMessageAlert.text = $"+{newMessageCount} new message(s)";, works, but others dont. besides, im not getting any logs.
i also tried to remove filestream, but it still didnt work.
i would be so happy if someone found the solution.
p.s. is there a better way to make the script wait other than while loop?

There are tons of ways for How to make the script wait/sleep in a simple way in unity ... mostly depends on your use case ... Note that most of the Unity API requires to be called from within the Unity main thread and can not be called from other background tasks/threads

so @derHugo what method do i have to use then

whatever suits you and your needs/taste best. All I can tell right now is you are trying to use TextMeshPro API from a background task/thread which will not work

alright, thanks a lot @derHugo.

so yeah, @derHugo found the solution and it had nothing to do with textmeshpro.
i had a several of issues in the code so im going to list it down below:

i was using async to call a new method in unity c# which deffinetly did not work.
i was using while loops in unity c# to make the code wait and that was another issue, because the code didnt start at the first place.

if someone wants to know how i fixed it, i would tell that used another script which had update in it to call the method written above.
thanks again @derHugo
